# How are arrays used in JOptionPane.showOptionDialog?

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am currently using a custom `showOptionDialog` in my program with five buttons. Each of those buttons are "connected" to an "if" statement. Usually, I would use something like this:

```
 if (a == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){}
```

but, as it is a custom array, I don't quite know what to do. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The returned value is the index, in the array of options, of the selected option.